# Table Header Overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have two sets of headers above a table, the second row is for each column, and the first groups those columns together.

[image]

Is there any way I could make it so that the top row overflows into the other columns without widening the columns below if I increase the font size, as I would like it to be that way if possible. But I feel like I have tried all possibilities with the css overflow option.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
print '<table>';
print '<tr><th></th><th class ="tover">Exception Confirmed</th><th></th><th>
</th><th class ="tover">Last Object Deleted</th><th></tr>';
 print '<tr><th>Date / Time</th><th>User ID</th><th>Location</th><th>Date / 
Time</th><th>User ID</th><th>UL ID</tr>';
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS + OCI_ASSOC)) {
    print '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $item) {
        print '<td class="tswid">' . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, 
ENT_QUOTES) : '') . '</td>';
    }

    print '</tr>';
}

print '</table>';

.tover{
overflow: hidden;
font-size:medium;
}

th,
td {
padding: .5em 1em;
vertical-align: top;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 14px;
}

table {
background-color: transparent;
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.table {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Edit: I managed to get it working with suggestions from the comments, but for some reason it is now aligned to the right and will not change. Any ideas?

[[image]]

Comment: It's a little hard to confirm this works (as you're using PHP for your actual table content), but you *should* be able to achieve this with `.tover {
overflow: auto; }`. Can you try that?

Comment: Yea I just didn't think the PHP would matter in this situation. overflow: auto; was one of the first things I tried, it still makes the cells underneath become wider.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I managed to get it to nearly work the visible and another small tweak. Any chance you could look at my edit and see if you have any ideas?

Comment: A table will automatically overflow elements to contain the content, so you can't set the `width`. You probably need to set `table { display: block; }`, and then work from there. However, if you could post the HTML instead of the PHP, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be much easier to diagnose, as it would be possible to replicate the issue =]